# How to change 4 repeated digits in roman numerals converter?

Tags: c, arrays, return-value, roman-numerals

I am writing a program that converts an integer from 0 to 3999 into its roman numerals equivalent.

Currently, my main function, which actually does the converting, works fine. It takes in a number, uses the roman numeral variables to make up the roman numeral array until the integer the user entered becomes 0:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int num;
    char roman[10];
    int I = 1, V = 5, X = 10, L = 50, C = 100, D = 500, M = 1000;

    printf("Please input a number from 1 to 3999:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    do {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (num >= M) {
                num -= M;
                roman[j] = 'M';
            }
            else if (num >= D) {
                num -= D;
                roman[j] = 'D';
            }
            else if (num >= C) {
                num -= C;
                roman[j] = 'C';
            }
            else if (num >= L) {
                num -= L;
                roman[j] = 'L';
            }
            else if (num >= X) {
                num -= X;
                roman[j] = 'X';
            }
            else if (num >= V) {
                num -= V;
                roman[j] = 'V';
            }
            else if (num >= I) {
                num -= I;
                roman[j] = 'I';
            }
        }
    } while (num != 0);

    // check(roman, 'X');

        printf("\nYour number in roman numerals is %s\n", roman);
}
```

On the commented line is a separate function (called `check()`) that I wrote. This new function should ideally check for any letter that is repeated 4 times, and return true if there is such a case or false if not. It looks like this:

```
int check(char * numeralArray, char numeral)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int size = strlen(numeralArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(numeralArray[i] == numeral)     // check for each iteration if numeral is in numeralArray[i]
            counter++;     // if it is then counter increases by 1
        else
            counter = 0;    // this resets the value to 0 if its not consecutive.

        if(counter == 4)    // this stops the loop when 4 consecutive letters have been found.
            break;
    }

    if(counter >= 4)    // if counter is 4, it means 4 consecutive letters have been found
        return 1;   // true
    else
        return 0;   // false
}
```

So the idea is that I would use the function and pass `roman` and `I` as arguments to `check()`, for example. It would then check if `I` comes up 4 times consecutively. If it does, the function returns true (represented by 1). In my main function, if the value returned from `check()` is 1 (true), then I would want to change these four consecutive values (e.g. `IIII`) into the appropriate value (e.g. `IV`).

The problem is, it does not work as it should, the `check()` function always returns 0 (false), even when I type in a number like 14, where instead of `XIIII`, it should be `XIV`. So I don't know how to get my function to return true in this case and then what would I have to do in order to make the desired change to the array? Also, in my main function, do I necessarily need a for loop inside the do-while loop? Or can I get rid of the for loop and just increment through the array each time the do-while loop runs (like this `j++`)?

Comment: I'd like to suggest that there are better ways to organize the conversion than to generate 4 letters and then remap those letters.  However, what you're seeking to do should be doable, even if not very convenient.  Note that VIIII should be mapped to IX, but IIII should be mapped to IV.  That is, finding the quad isn't sufficient; you also have to examine the letter before it (if there is one; XXIIII needs to map to XIV; XXXXIIII needs to map to XLIV, etc).

Comment: The check function definitely works, there is probably a problem with the arguments you're passing (notice uppercase vs lowercase). Also, you could already implement that functionality in the conversion function

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I do agree there must be an easier way and my way is very inefficient if you take into account what you said about the previous letters. The one thing I find really difficult is that once the quadruple letters have been identified, how would I change them in the array? I'm not very fluent with arrays or pointers, so this is where I had to come onto SO and ask about it.

Comment: I use a data structure which contains a number and a string. For example, the first two entries are `1000, "M"` and `900, "CM"`.  I use this to guide the formatting.  Scanning — converting from roman to decimal — needs more information but uses the same core data.

Comment: I think I know what you mean about substituting letters. I wrote a second version of the program that uses a similar concept, it's not as efficient as this, but it kind of works. If you want to see it, let me know and I'll post it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Used correctly, your `check()` function works correctly.  Here's a minimal `main()` function that tests it:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *str[] = { "IIII", "XIIII", "XIII", "IIIXIIII", "IIIXIII" };
    enum { NUM_STR = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STR; i++)
        printf("%s: %d\n", str[i], check(str[i], 'I'));

    return 0;
}
```

Output;

```
IIII: 1
XIIII: 1
XIII: 0
IIIXIIII: 1
IIIXIII: 0
```

So, the problem you've got isn't with the `check()` function per se.

---

Here's an alternative way of formatting Roman numerals.  It uses a table to determine what's acceptable (and limits the range of numbers to 1 .. 3999).  In my main library, the structure has two extra fields to help with parsing and validating Roman numeral strings, converting them to an `int`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Header "roman.h" */
extern int fmt_roman(int i, char *buffer, size_t buflen);
/* End "roman.h" */

typedef struct Roman
{
    int           value;
    const char    chars[3];
} Roman;

enum { MAX_PERMITTED_ROMAN = 4000 };

static const Roman numerals[] =
{
    {   1000,   "M",    },
    {    900,   "CM",   },
    {    500,   "D",    },
    {    400,   "CD",   },
    {    100,   "C",    },
    {     90,   "XC",   },
    {     50,   "L",    },
    {     40,   "XL",   },
    {     10,   "X",    },
    {      9,   "IX",   },
    {      5,   "V",    },
    {      4,   "IV",   },
    {      1,   "I",    },
};
enum { NUM_NUMERALS = sizeof(numerals) / sizeof(numerals[0]) };

int fmt_roman(int i, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    int rc = -1;

    if (i <= 0 || i > MAX_PERMITTED_ROMAN)
        errno = EDOM;
    else if (buflen <= 1)
        errno = ENOSPC;
    else
    {
        char *end = buffer + buflen;
        char *dst = buffer;
        const Roman *e = numerals + NUM_NUMERALS;

        for (const Roman *r = numerals; i > 0 && r < e; r++)
        {
            while (i >= r->value)
            {
                const char *src = r->chars;
                char c;
                while ((c = *src++) != '\0' && dst < end)
                    *dst++ = c;
                if (dst >= end)
                    break;
                i -= r->value;
            }
        }
        if (dst < end)
        {
            *dst = '\0';
            rc = 0;
        }
        else
            errno = ENOSPC;
    }
    return(rc);
}
```

As usual, quite a lot of the code is associated with error handling.

Comment: Is it to do with the arguments, as Zach P said? It's kind of confusing, since I'm not a seasoned programmer, so to speak. Also, what does `enum` mean? I've seen it before but I don't quite know what it is?

Comment: Probably, but since we can't see your non-working calls to the function, it is hard to know.  However, the problem is not in the function — that means it is probably in the code that calls the function.

Comment: I'll also observe that the interface to `check()` isn't particularly useful.  You need to know where the sequence starts so that you can map it accurately.  You should never see repeats of V, L, D (the 'fives').

Comment: Update: the `check()` function does actually work, I tried it out in the terminal. It doesn't work in Xcode though, so I'll just have to carry on manually compiling it from now on. But ok, that makes sense, the function works, so now it's just the issue of sorting out the array wherever there are quadruples.

Comment: Not working in XCode but working from the command line makes very little sense.

Comment: How do you mean? I personally prefer the command line; I find it more rewarding to learn how to compile programs as opposed to using an IDE and not being able to figure out why it won't compile for you. I generally use a text editor like Sublime Text, but nevertheless, I want to be able to learn how to use Xcode for future development.

Comment: What I meant was 'the program' or 'the check function' not working when run via XCode but working when run at the command line is not the (mis)behaviour I'd expect. I use the command line mainly for development too.  Even on the Mac where I mainly work.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I interpreted that wrongly. I thought you meant there's no point using the command line when you have a full IDE. Could it perhaps be because of the LLVM compiler that Xcode uses? I've read that it's used as a hybrid with GCC (which is what I'm used to), but there may be slight differences. This isn't really my area of expertise :)